# php continue execution after leaving the page

Tags: php, flush, continue

I have a simple script that counts from 1 to 5000 with a `for` loop. It flushes output in real time to browser and shows a progress bar with %.

What I have: If I leave the page, the process interrupts. If I come back, it starts from 0.

What I want to achieve: If I leave the page, the process continues and, If I come back , it shows the right percentage.

Example: I run the process, it counts till 54, I leave the page for 10 seconds, when I come back it shows me 140 and continues to flush.

Is it possible?

Comment: you'd have to have the task running in a completely separate process e.g. via a cron job or something. The web page script would be used only to monitor the progress.

Comment: Could be possible with a session I guess.

Comment: @ADyson but If I use cron job , how do I catch its current percentage in another page which monitores the execution?

Comment: well, the job would have to write the current status somewhere at regular intervals, e.g. into a text file or database table or something. Then the webpage could read it from there at regular intervals.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689506/how-to-continue-php-script-after-sending-http-response/68696515#68696515 I had the same question, this might help others as it closes the connection but the script keeps running!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to use server workers - scripts which are intended to run independently from webserver context.

The most common way of doing it - usage of message queues (RabbitMQ, Qless, etc). Event should be initiated by the script in web context, but the actual task should be executed by queue listener in a different context.

Comment: Interesting.. so If use those queue listeners , am I able to catch their progresses in another page and display the correct percentage even leaving the page?

Comment: @DregKorig, workers can modify the state which can be read by the web script. For example changing the counter in Redis or DB.

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked seems quite simple to do with a session. (Purely assuming on the use case given). This is not running any process in the background, it just simply keep track of the time and show the progress. That's why I said "based on what you asked". If you want to keep track of any real background tasks, then I believe the case would be totally different, and you will have to change the wordings of your question as well ;)

Something like this would do.

```
<?php
session_start();
$s = &$_SESSION;

$sleep = 1; //seconds

//check if we have a value set in session before, if not set default = 0.
if(!isset($s['last'])){
    $s['last'] = 0;
}

//check if we have a last time set in session before. if not set a default = curret time.
if(!isset($s['time'])){
    $s['time'] = time();
}

//get the idle time of the user.
$idle = time() - $s['time'];

//start the loop..and set starting point.
$start = $s['last'] + ($idle / $sleep);

for( $i = $start; $i < 100; $i++){
    echo $i . '<br />';
    $s['last']++;
    $s['time'] = time();
    flush();
    sleep($sleep);
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I think, that the intention is not about changing the value of a counter, but doing the task even if the user closed the tab.

Comment: Yes, that's what i mentioned in my answer.